# Adding references in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, reference, visual-studio-2013

I have some problems with adding references. I created Windows Phone project in Visual Studio 2013 and I need to add references `System.Web.Extensions` to use `System.Web.Script.Serialization`.

[image: screenshot from vs]

But when I right-click and choose "add reference", there is no such variant in the list, just some namespaces, connected to windows phone developing.

Also, there is an ability to add references to other projects from solution, but here I have the second problem - I can't add reference to simple class library, for example. It says me, that I can just add references to windows phone projects..

So, when can I read about changes in the reference system in VS2013 (and 2012 as I remember)? How to add reference to `System.Web.Extensions` in my WP project? And is there an ability to use custom class libraries with references in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only assemblies created for Windows Phone are available in Windows Phone project references. This limitation isn't specific to Visual Studio 2013, older versions of Visual Studio has the same behavior.

Similar rule applies for the 2nd problem. You need to make the other project type be Windows Phone class library or Portable Class Library (PCL) that support Windows Phone, instead of common class library.

Comment: Do you mean, that I can't use System.Web.Script.Serialization in wp project?

Comment: As far as I know, no. I'm quite sure about that, unless you ever managed to use it in any version of VS (have you?)

Comment: I could add reference to simple class library in VS2010, I'm sure. But can't in VS2012, so I just replaced classes to main project. But now I have a problem with Serialization, it's more important. In 2012 I can't use it and I don't know about 2010, can't check now. But anyway, is it normal? How to deserialize json string from server in wp project?....

Comment: [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) (or install it from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)) is widely used library to work with JSON.